# How to fix: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy' import error

Tags: python, scipy, pip

I am setting up a speech recognition software using mozilla and want to use the pre-trained model.

This is for macosx, I have already installed pip and the related scipy file however my system cant seem to pull the scipy module when I run my python script. Could it be that this is installed in another directory from the virtual env itself?

```
Terminal
(deepspeech-venv) Chabanis-MacBook-Pro:deepspeech chabani$ pip3 list
Package    Version
---------- -------
deepspeech 0.5.1  
numpy      1.17.0 
pip        19.2.1 
scipy      1.3.1  
setuptools 41.0.1 
wheel      0.33.4 

Python
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav // this is the issue here

Terminal - deepspeech path
(deepspeech-venv) Chabanis-MacBook-Pro:deepspeech chabani$ which deepspeech
/Users/chabani/tmp/deepspeech-venv/bin/deepspeech

=== RESTART: /Users/chabani/tmp/deepspeech-venv/lib/python3.7/activate.py ===
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/chabani/tmp/deepspeech-venv/lib/python3.7/activate.py", line 7, in <module>
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
```

Comment: Which version of `Python` you are using? Might be that you installed `scipy` for a different version from the one you are using now.

Comment: Try `pip3 list`, check if you have `scipy` or `scikit-learn`

Comment: Hi Guys sorry for the delayed response. @ Dennis.M, Yes got it to work by installing scipy.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa, thanks for the response, yes i was missing the scipy installation.

Answer (score -1):

try to run this command:
 pip3 install scipy

Comment: He had done that already.